# Закачка файла методом POST на WAMPSERVERE

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с методом POST на WAMPSERVERE, речь идет о закачке файла. Вот html форма:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ufile" action="upload.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000" />
   <input name="ufile" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
```

Она работает и позволяет выбрать фотку. Но в скрипте обработки я получаю такую информацию через phpinfo():

```
_FILES["userfile"]
    [name] => Las.jpg - это оригинальное название фотки
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => С:\wamp\tmp\php8B15.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 8652
```

Казалось бы, все хорошо, ошибок нет, файл закачан. Но в папке `C:\\wamp\tmp`, куда он должен временно размещаться с временным именем php8B15.tmp его НЕТ! Короче, файл не закачивается или не записывается в эту папку. Там только сессии.

Я останавливал скрипт до перемещения временного файла и такая картина. В свойствах папки стоит флажок "Только чтение" и изменить его не удается. Впрочем, такие флажки почти на 
всех папках и все туда прекрасно пишется. Например, пишутся же в `C:\\wamp\tmp` сессии. А закачиваемый файл - нет.

Я пытаюсь закачать на локальный сервер файл с моего же компьютера и ничего не получается. Причем вручную он в эту папку прекрасно записывается и удаляется.

В чем дело, кто знает, помогите!

Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, там уже прописано: 
upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"

Answer (score 1):

В php.ini укажи каталог, в который можешь писать, параметр:

```
upload_tmp_dir = 'путь/куда/можно/писать'
```